# Why a change in routing policy in tornado results in sending Type Error?

Tags: python, tornado

I am trying to change the whole webpages from serving on absolute path to relative path, but something went wrong as the request goes to the back-end tornado 5.0 server.

The javascript is like this:

```
             $.ajax({
                 url:'../pyctp/get_ctp_info.ctp',
                 type:'post',
                 dataType:'json',
                 data:{"InstrumentID":""}, 
                 success:function(response){
```

The nginx will proxy_pass any thing that ends with `.ctp` to the server. `url` used to be `/pyctp/get_ctp_info.ctp` but both cases fell into the server error code 500.

Because I add the original routing url `r'/pyctp/(.*)\.(.*)'` with `(.*)` on the front :

```
    app = Application([ 
 ...    
        (r'(.*)/pyctp/(.*)\.(.*)', CTPManageMentHandler),
    ],
...
```

The url is not pure regular expression, so I try to mimic what worked, allowing some path ahead of `/pyctp/get_ctp_info.ctp`

Here is the error recorded by python:

```
TypeError: write() only accepts bytes, unicode, and dict objects
ERROR:tornado.access:500 POST /pyctp/get_ctp_info.ctp (127.0.0.1) 1.93ms
ERROR:tornado.application:Uncaught exception POST /pyctp/get_ctp_info.ctp (127.0.0.1)
HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='139.198.17.235', method='POST', uri='/pyctp/get_ctp_info.ctp', version='HTTP/1.0', remote_ip='127.0.0.1')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/pyenv/quotecli/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1499, in _stack_context_handle_exception
    raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
  File "<string>", line 4, in raise_exc_info
  File "/pyenv/quotecli/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 315, in wrapped
    ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/pyenv/quotecli/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1711, in future_complete
    f.result()
  File "/pyenv/quotecli/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 1113, in run
    yielded = self.gen.send(value)
  File "/root/QuoteClientMajor/server_router.py", line 118, in post
    self.write(result)
  File "/pyenv/quotecli/lib/python3.8/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 739, in write
    raise TypeError(message)
```

here is the whole `CTPManageMentHandler` class  in `server_router.py`

```
class CTPManageMentHandler(base.RequestHandler):
    executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(8)
    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def get(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url_pattern = args[0]
        param = get_param(self.request.query_arguments, self.session_id)
        result = yield self.get_result(url_pattern, param=param, *args, **kwargs)
        self.write(result)
        self.finish()

    @run_on_executor
    def get_result(self, url_type, *args, **kwargs):
        result = self.ctp_management( url_type, *args, **kwargs)
        return result

    @tornado.web.asynchronous
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url_pattern = args[0]
        #print(self.request.headers.get("X-Real-IP"))
        request_data = self.request.body.decode('utf8')
        param = get_param(self.request.query_arguments, self.session_id)
        if '&' in request_data or '=' in request_data:
            request_data = json.dumps(utils.map_to_json(request_data))
        
        result = yield self.post_result(url_pattern, request_data, param=param, *args, **kwargs)
        self.write(result) #【【here is where the error occured】】
        self.finish()

    @run_on_executor
    def post_result(self, url_type, request_data, *args, **kwargs):
        result = self.ctp_management(url_type, request_data, *args, **kwargs)
        return result

    def ctp_management(self, url_type, request_data=None, *args, **kwargs):
        if url_type == 'get_ctp_info':
            return PyCTPManager.CTPInterface.get_ctp_info(self,request_data)
```

So why is the TypeError? Or is there a right way to express some url that ends with `/pyctp/get_ctp_info.ctp` to let tornado route it?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found the cause:

`(r'(.*)/pyctp/(.*)\.(.*)', CTPManageMentHandler),` rather than the original `r'/pyctp/(.*)\.(.*)'` passed the additional argument, the path before `/pyctp/` to the handler `CTPManageMentHandler`. That root path is caught by `url_pattern = args[0]`, which was `get_ctp_info`, and got further passed on as `url_type` to other functions after `post` and resulted in `None` after `ctp_management` got executed.